# How to hide a buffer thru vimscript, with buffer number or buffer name

Tags: vimscript, neovim, buffers, terminal-buffer

I'm trying to make a plugin that hide and show a terminal window on the bottom of the window, but i can't find a reliable way to hide a specific buffer, i tried using `hide` but you only can hide by count, and not by window number or name.

Comment: Could you use [`:h getbufinfo()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getbufinfo%28%29) to get the windows in which the buffer is shown and either hide all of them or use [`:h gettabinfo()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#gettabinfo%28%29) to get the windows in the current tab and close only the window intersecting the buffer in the current tab?

Comment: how can i clone close only the window intersecting the buffer in the current tab?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if you're mixing up buffers and windows here... `:hide` will hide a window by count, the window numbers are determined depending on their positions. On the other hand, there's buffer numbers (those shown by `:ls`), maybe you want to refer to those? There's for example `:bd` to "delete" (essentially hide?) a buffer by its buffer number...